# How to access/ping a server located on AWS?

Tags: dns, ip-address, amazon-web-services

With what address should a server located on AWS be accessed?

I've created an AWS instance and installed a web server on it. However the server is not reachable via any of the:

1. ec2-174-129-24-92.compute-1.amazonaws.com
2. the IP address from instance's `ifconfig`
3. an elastic IP address I've created on the AWS dashboard and associated with the instance

Surprisingly, ssh with `root@ec2-174-129-24-92.compute-1.amazonaws.com` works fine.

What might be the problem and how to bind an address to the instance?

Answer (score 32):

In your security group open -1 to -1 on ICMP for range 0.0.0.0/0 and you'll be able to ping.

See my screenshot for a better view:

[image: AWS Console Image]

Image posted by @emostar below

Comment: The image is no longer available.

Comment: Apart from this, If you are behind a corporate network then do check with network admin dept if they haven't blocked access to all ports other than 80 (http) & 22 (ssh). We spend a lot of time figuring out why we were unable to connect to our application running on 2181 port and later found that our network was the one that discarded packets not destined to 80,22 port.

Comment: NOTE: When I did this it took a while (at least 20 minutes) to propagate.  I rebooted about 3 times, waiting in between, after opening up ICMP access.  I went out shopping and when I came back - voila!  It was working.  Don't know if this is usual or a quirk I ran across this once.

Answer (score 17):

**Updated for 2014** - the current Amazon UI no longer uses numbers for ICMP types, so the existing answer doesn't work anymore.

In your security group:

- Click the **inbound** tab
- Create a **custom ICMP rule**
- Select **echo request**
- Use **range 0.0.0.0/0** for everyone or lock it down to specific IPs
- Apply the changes

and you'll be able to ping.

[image: AWS Console Image]

Comment: PSA WARNING: select `echo request` and not `echo reply`. otherwise you may lose hours going  crazy

Comment: Ack @BKSpurgeon 'ping' is 'ICMP Echo Request'. The echo reply is the ping response. You want to allow incoming requests (and outbound replies).

Answer (score 11):

As nowthatsamatt said, you want to allow ICMP from all addreses.

To do this on the command line you can run:

```
ec2-authorize <group> -P icmp -t -1:-1 -s 0.0.0.0/0
```

Or if you prefer the AWS Console, this is what it would look like (current as of 2012-09-19):

[AWS Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9LL5.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

Ping doesn't work with EC2 because ping runs over the ICMP protocol which is blocked in a typical EC2 security group configuration.

Here's a very nifty way to work around this by using [tcping](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php) (a ping alternative that works over a TCP port):

`tcping ec2-174-129-24-92.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

`tcping ec2-174-129-24-92.compute-1.amazonaws.com 22`

It runs on port 80 (the first example) but you can also specify a different port (the second example) to be used to test connectivity.

Comment: `tcping` without providing a host won't work (Tested on mac with homebrew version of tcping). It produces the following error: `error: Usage: tcping [-q] [-t timeout_sec] [-u timeout_usec] <host> <port>`

Answer (score 7):

Give 2 rules in AWS security group (Inbound),

```
Custom ICMP Rule       Echo Request          N/A            0.0.0.0/0

Custom ICMP Rule       Echo Reply            N/A             0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 6):

Eight years late but hopefully this will help someone else...

The below shows how to enable the ports needed for pings.

1) First make sure the EC2 instance has a public IP. It has a **Public DNS** or **Public IP** address then you should be good. This should also be the address you ping.
[image: AWS public DNS address]

2) Go to the **Security Group** that EC2 is using.

- right click, select **inbound rules**
- A: select **Add Rule**
- B: Select **Custom ICMP Rule - IPv4**
- C: Select **Echo Request**
- D: Select either **Anywhere** or **My IP** *(note: **My IP** is more secure then **anyone** but will only allow pings from your IP.)*
- E: Select **Save**

[image: Add a Security Group ICMP Rule to allow Pings and Echos]

3) Create a windows firewall exception.

- Go to **Start** and type **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security**
- Select **inbound rules**

[image: Add a Windows Server ICMP Rule to allow Pings and Echos]

Comment: awesome. some of you might also want to allow "edge traversal" and you can do so through the properties submenu as show in the diagram above.

Answer (score 2):

If your instance uses a Windows AMI you need to make sure that both the security group on the AWS console AND the Windows Firewall are set up to accept connections on the port(s) you require.

I had the same issue enabling http access until I configured the Windows firewall to allow connections on the ports I wanted. This is easily done in Windows by accessing Control Panel>System and Security>Windows Firewall>Advanced Settings. Then configure a new port rule to allow incoming TCP traffic to the port or port range you require.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE for September 2014:
After a while of not being able to apt-get without freezing, I tried to ping www.google.com.  To my surprise I couldn't ping either.  I followed the suggestion above by creating a new ICMP rule with an Echo Request for Inbound.  This didn't work for me either.  After much trying I created a new rule for Outbound with Echo Request.  Now it works.  Maybe AWS added this recently?  Anyway, hope this helps somebody out there.  Not being able to do something as simple as pinging could drive a person nuts.

edit: now my apt-get works too!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue while connecting from my local mac machine

Work around as below:

1. *** Route table => add 0.0.0.0/0 and target to your Internet Gateway ***
2. Under Network ACL add ad below

   2.1 for pings from your local machine ->

   All ICMP - IPv4 ICMP (1) ALL 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW

   2.2 ssh/other connectivity

   ```
   SSH (22) TCP (6) 22 0.0.0.0/0

   ALL Traffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0
   ```
3. Good practice associate your subnet to your route table
4. Under Ec2 -> Security Group

   4.1 To allow SSH connectivity, just add as below

   ```
   SSH (22) TCP (6) 22 0.0.0.0/0
   ```

   4.2 for pings to work from your local machine as as below

   ```
   All ICMP - IPv4 All N/A 0.0.0.0/0
   ```

This will make your connectivity works for pings & ssh from your local machine using your KEY file (xx.pem)

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you install a VPN server on your AWS server, you can connect to the VPN and ping the private IP address in the virtual private network.