# Pinging EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm new to managing EC2 instances. I have created one, and I can run it and remotely login with Windows Remote Desktop. I can ping external servers from inside my instance, but I cannot ping the instance from my machine using its DNS public name.
I guess I'm doing something wrong with security groups.
Any thoughts anybody?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465076/how-to-access-ping-a-server-located-on-aws

Comment: I believe this question is valid and should not have been closed. This is regarding the security group settings which involves opening the related ports.

Answer (score 70):

To ping an EC2 instance, you need to allow ICMP traffic in the instance's security group.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, Amazon is blocking ICMP (ping) requests. If you want to perform some sort of "is it up" request you may want to implement some other routine like a web based "ping" page; just have it display the time when you hit it.

Comment: This isn't currently the case - you just need to allow ICMP inbound traffic as indicated above.  NOTE: It took about 10-20 minutes for my changes to go through...

Comment: Yes, as with many things in life this changed; it is now an option in your security group. My answer was only valid for a few years.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Since I wasn't looking at AWS when this was posted, I had no experience of the "way it was" so I can only speak of the current situation.  I was concerned that my statement might be taken as a criticism of the original post; there is no such intent - these things sometimes change almost daily ;-)

Comment: As @rholmes said, this takes a while to go through. I thought I was doing something wrong and gave up until I saw this. Thanks! It should probably be part of one of the answers instead of being hidden here in comments.

Comment: Down-votes 6+ years later, what a jerk you are, whoever you are.. Much Karma to you pal