# Hadoop datanodes cannot find namenode in standalone setup

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

There are no errors in any log but I believe my datanode cannot find my namenode.

This is the error that leads me to this conclusion (according to what I've found online):

```
[INFO ]: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: /hadoop.server:9000. Already tried 4 time(s).
```

jps output:

```
7554 Jps
7157 NameNode
7419 SecondaryNameNode
7251 DataNode
```

Please can someone offer some advice?

Result of dfsadmin

```
Configured Capacity: 13613391872 (12.68 GB)
Present Capacity: 9255071744 (8.62 GB)
DFS Remaining: 9254957056 (8.62 GB)
DFS Used: 114688 (112 KB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 1 (1 total, 0 dead)

Live datanodes:
Name: 192.172.1.49:50010 (Hadoop)
Hostname: Hadoop
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 13613391872 (12.68 GB)
DFS Used: 114688 (112 KB)
Non DFS Used: 4358320128 (4.06 GB)
DFS Remaining: 9254957056 (8.62 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 67.98%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Last contact: Fri Aug 08 17:25:57 SAST 2014
```

Comment: Please give more details of Error message

Comment: i extended the error message. it just repeats. its not actually an error message... just info (just realised). there is no error message anywhere...

Comment: hadoop dfsadmin -report .Try this command.It should show report of connected nodes

Comment: I had similar issues that ended up being from an incorrect /etc/hosts file.

Comment: added the dfsadmin output

Comment: what was wrong the with /etc/hosts file? mine has only 2 lines: 

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

Comment: Looks fine. Are you able to put files into the hdfs?

Comment: yes I can. i'm trying to connect from a client on another machine but i can't seem to be able to...

Comment: Can you check that NameNode is listening on non-localhost address (non 127.0.0.1)? Namenode's port is 8020 or 9000.

Comment: I have written one answer. See if that helps.

Comment: This post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872807/hadoop-datanodes-cannot-find-namenode.

Answer (score 1):

Give a hostname to your machines and make their entries in the /etc/hosts file,  like this ,

```
#hostname hdserver.example.com
#vim /etc/hosts
192.168.0.25 hdserver.example.com
192.168.0.30 hdclient.example.com
```

and save it.(Use correct IP addresses)

On client also give hostname hdclient.example.com and make above entries in /etc/hosts. This will help the nameserver to locate the machines with hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

delete all contents from tmp folder: rm -Rf path/of/tmp/directory

format  namenode:                  :bin/hadoop namenode -format

start all processes again          : bin/start-all.sh