# how to connect localhost as client and server in hadoop same user in ubuntu

Tags: hadoop

If client and server in same ubuntu machine, not able to connect.
giving error

> Call From ashish/127.0.0.1 to localhost:54310 failed on connection
>   exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more
>   details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Answer (score 0):

By `server` do you mean `namenode`? By client do you mean `hadoop client`, `datanode`, `nodemanager`? Are you sure namenode is running and exposed on `localhost:54310`? Could you try

```
> nc -vz localhost 54310
```

How does your `/etc/hosts` look like? How does your `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` looks like? What do you get for (as your hadoop user):

```
> jps -ml
```

What do you get for:

```
> sudo iptables -L
```

Also take a look at:

- [Hadoop cluster setup - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661285/hadoop-cluster-setup-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)
- [Hadoop Datanodes cannot find NameNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872807/hadoop-datanodes-cannot-find-namenode)

Comment: on nc -vz localhost 54310getting nc: connect to localhost port 54310 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

Comment: i am not able to start namenode so i have started secondarynamenode. It is still still saying connection refused

Comment: @ashishSinghal secondary namenode is not the same thing as primary namenode. Please read hadoop documentation -> https://hadoop.apache.org/#Getting+Started Work your way, step by step - make sure the all the pieces of the cluster are healthy before you move further. Having active NN/master is crucial - start there.