# Hadoop Multi-Node Cluster: exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: hadoop

I have set up 4 nodes hadoop cluster using `http://pingax.com/install-apache-hadoop-ubuntu-cluster-setup/`:

Namenode: node04
Datanode: node01
Datanode: node02
Datanode: node03

I can see only two nodes(node01,node03) running in my cluster. Node02 has an log with error message as:

```
2015-12-11 10:15:18,698 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: node04/127.17.0.224:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-11 10:15:19,699 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: node04/127.17.0.224:9000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-11 10:15:20,699 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: node04/127.17.0.224:9000. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

Every nodes /etc/hosts contains following:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

127.17.0.221    node01
127.17.0.222    node02
127.17.0.223    node03
127.17.0.224    node04
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

And /etc/hadoop/masters contains `node04`, /etc/hadoop/slaves contains `node01 node02` and `node03`

Would you please help me understand how to get to it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perform these actions:

1. Go to node02 and run `telnet node04 9000` and `ping node04` commands
   to confirm there is connectivity between node02 and node04
2. On all nodes check whether core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml have the same contents

Comment: telnet node04 9000 has the following output: Trying 127.17.0.224...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: ping node04 has output: PING node04 (127.17.0.224) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from node04 (127.17.0.224): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.020 ms
64 bytes from node04 (127.17.0.224): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.008 ms

Comment: i do have same configurations for core-site.xml and hfs-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

1. Check ssh and sshd
2. ssh connection between the nodes
3. Check port binding details ([Hadoop Datanodes cannot find NameNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872807/hadoop-datanodes-cannot-find-namenode))

Also refer https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ServerNotAvailable

Comment: I can ssh between node04(nematode) and node02(datanode).

Comment: Did you checked the mentioned links

Comment: Yeah, I tried those before asking the question here.