# Copy file to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I wanted to Copy file SalesJan2009.csv (stored on local file system, ~/input/SalesJan2009.csv) to HDFS (Hadoop Distributed File System) Home Directory

I wrote this code
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal '/home/hduser/Desktop/input/SalesJan2009.csv' /HDFS-path

and this is was the result:19/11/27 07:05:16 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /HDFS-path._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1814)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:846)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:871)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:817)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2606)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1507)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:444)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:710)
copyFromLocal: File /HDFS-path._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

Comment: Your HDFS is not set up properly. As it tells you, you have no active data nodes. You are supposed to have at least one. This is, of course, not a programming issue, but a problem in the configuration of your cluster, so it's not really appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, Cricket I will try to fix the HDFS

Answer (score 0):

The command which you gave for copying the file is correct.
But, it seems there is no active data nodes in your cluster. To do hdfs operations, at least one datanode is needed. Please check this.

Comment: Hi Priyanka, thanks for your help the Datanode wasn't running in my hadoop and when it starts working the namenode is gone.

Comment: I got the this error : copyFromLocal: Call From ubuntu/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: Hi Abdul, please refer this link - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872807/hadoop-datanodes-cannot-find-namenode]